# Why does my knee behave unexpectedly when manipulating the foot control in Rigify Blender rig?

Tags: rigging, rigify

The first image shows the problem I'm encountering, while the second one depicts the desired result which I achieved through manual adjustment of the knee control. How can I achieve this?

[image: The issue]

[image: Desired outcome]

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Notice the IK bone that is depicted as a unfilled red arrow in the upper leg: try rotating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I detect that you are using a character imported via DAZ Studio?

Notice the IK bone that is depicted as a unfilled red arrow in the upper leg:  it is probably named something like "thigh_ik.R"

Select this bone and try rotating it.  It is used in place of "IK pole targets" in some armatures like DAZ Studio,  and it rotates the thigh/knee alignment. As you can see from the screen-cap, this arrow-like bone is rotated 90-degrees (Z-axis) from what you show in your screen cap, and in my case will rotate the knee/thigh pointing forward.

[image]

More convenient is to create and use a pole target that you can move/animate instead of rotating the knee_ik bone.  The knee_ik bone will then rotate to Track_To the position of the pole target.

[image]

Also, if you want to make the adjusted rotation of the knee to be the default, use the Pose>>Apply as Rest Pose (either of the first two on the menu should work).   This is analogous to the *Apply >> Rotation* to objects.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping out! I'm actually using a model I sculpted in Blender, so it's weird for it to have such behavior. So I think I'm understanding Rigify a bit more with your explanation here. I tried rotating thigh_ik.R 90 degrees, and it solved the problem when I tried to move the foot. So my goal is to eventually rotate this every time I want to move my foot to prevent any distortions such as the one in the first image I posted, right? But why is my thigh_ik.R rotated the way it is, and can I fix it to be like the one in your pictures, i.e to be faced forward?

Comment: @Animimo -- I appended to my answer above.  Good followup question.  If you accept  my answer, could you please click the check mark near the top left of my answer.  Us poor contributers work for the reputation points we gain, LOL.

Comment: Yes, of course. Thank you for the detailed answer!